# Quick access arrays for time-series data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of log files holding onto various-rate time series data from sensors (some 1Hz, some 10Hz). The data is currently is spread across several different files and file formats (csv, xml, butchered versions of csv, etc.). So I want to store the data in a database to make it easier to access, query, etc.

As setup now, I use one row for every reading from my sensor (see `log_data` or `log2_data` below). Of I want to get all the readings from one log I can make the following call, which works great:

```
SELECT utc, xpos, ypos, zpos FROM log_data WHERE imported_log_id = 7;
```

but say I want to get logs from several files and keep them separated, the following will not work because they'll be one table

`SELECT utc, xpos, ypos, zpos FROM log_data WHERE imported_log_id = 7 OR imported_log_id = 8;`

or even more complicated (and likely) 
    SELECT utc, xpos, ypos, zpos FROM log_data WHERE imported_log_id = 7;
    SELECT utc, xpos, ypos, zpos FROM log_data WHERE imported_log_id = 8;
    SELECT utc, xvel, yvel, zvel FROM log2_data WHERE imported_log_id = 9;
    SELECT utc, xvel, yvel, zvel FROM log2_data WHERE imported_log_id = 10;

alternatively, I can call

```
SELECT utc, xpos, ypos, zpos FROM log_data WHERE imported_log_id = 7;
SELECT utc, xpos, ypos, zpos FROM log_data WHERE imported_log_id = 8;
SELECT utc, xvel, yvel, zvel FROM log2_data WHERE imported_log_id = 9;
SELECT utc, xvel, yvel, zvel FROM log2_data WHERE imported_log_id = 10;
```

and save them separately. This works, but is very slow when the number of logs gets large. Is there a way I can speed this up? Everything I've looked up says if I need to use arrays then I should re-think my design.

I tried changing the types to the ARRAY type in Postgres and it was *awesome*. 5-10X speedup depending on number of records requested. Problem is, I have to move all of this from Postgres to SQL Server, so I can't use arrays. Very sad. I haven't been able to get table-valued parameters in SQL Server to work for this.

So how do I make these queries fast in a clean way?

Ideas I've thought of, none of which seems very good:

- Switch back to Postgres (I wish)
- Save the arrays as a comma-separate VARCHAR(8000) then parse when I query. (seems super hokey, and won't work when the values are themselves varchars)
- Just query everything, then sort result set by imported_log_id (using python, which wouldn't be too bad but again seems wrong)

My tables are below:

```
-- The type of data (e.g., POS, VEL)
CREATE TABLE imported_log_type
(
    imported_log_type_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    imported_log_type_name VARCHAR(8000)
);
-- The raw data
CREATE TABLE imported_log
(
    imported_log_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Type of the data
    imported_log_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES imported_log_type(imported_log_type_id),
    -- Original file name
    orig_filename VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL,
    -- Blob of original data
    orig_file_data VARBINARY(8000) NOT NULL
);


-- The parsed data
CREATE TABLE log_data
(
    log_data_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Relates to a specific log. One-to-many
    imported_log_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES imported_log(imported_log_id),

    utc DOUBLE PRECISION,
    elapsed_time DOUBLE PRECISION,
    xpos DOUBLE PRECISION,
    ypos DOUBLE PRECISION,
    zpos DOUBLE PRECISION
)

-- The parsed data
    CREATE TABLE log2_data
    (
        log2_data_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        -- Relates to a specific log. One-to-many
        imported_log_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES imported_log(imported_log_id),

        utc DOUBLE PRECISION,
        elapsed_time DOUBLE PRECISION,
        xvel DOUBLE PRECISION,
        yvel DOUBLE PRECISION,
        zvel DOUBLE PRECISION
    )
```

Comment: where do you query `log2_data`?

Comment: the query for log2_data is identical. I'll add the example.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT utc, xpos, ypos, zpos
FROM log_data
WHERE imported_log_id = 7;
```

You want an index on `log_data(imported_log_id)`.  You can keep additional columns in the index as well.

Given the way that you are loading the data, you can make this a clustered index, and that should be a big boost to performance.

Note:  You can handle the two queries as one:

```
SELECT imported_log_id, utc, xpos, ypos, zpos
FROM log_data
WHERE imported_log_id IN (7, 8);
```